# Is there a reason to use templates while implementing a SetMember method?

Tags: c++

While browsing our code, I noticed this:

```
class foo
{
  public:
      template <typename T>
      void SetBar(T&& otherBarInstance) { m_barInstance = std::forward<T>(otherBarInstance); }

  private:
      bar m_barInstance;  
};
```

In what scenarios (meaning, for what `T`'s) this would work other than for `T == bar`? (as far as I know, classes that derive from `bar` would fail since `m_barInstance` isn't declared as `bar&`)

Also , since `m_barInstance` is declared as `bar` and not as `bar&` , does the `std::forward` have any meaning here?

Comment: It would work for example for `bar = double` and `T = int`. More interestingly, it would work for `bar = std::unique_ptr<Base>` and `T = std::unique_ptr<Derived>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first question: it will work for all `T`s for which an implicit conversion to `bar` exists (such as a single-parameter constructor of `bar` taking a `T`).

I believe that the function exists as just a shorthand for this:

```
void SetBar(const bar &src) { m_barInstance = src; }
void SetBar(bar &&src) { m_barInstance = std::move(src); }
```

The problem is that (current) C++ doesn't allow forwarding references of a restricted type: something like "accept both lvalues and rvalues of type `bar` as efficiently as possible" cannot be expressed with a single template. The full perfect forwarding is the next best thing, and essentially provides almost the same functionality.

The single perfect forwarding function template in your code is actually even more efficient than the two overloads I've listed above, as it saves on one move when an implicit conversion happens. But moves are normally supposed to be fast.

Comment: *it saves on one move when an implicit conversion happens* Could you elaborate more on this? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @Lingxi Consider passing a `const char*` to a function which assigns to a `std::string`. If the function takes a `std::string`, that's a conversion from `const char*` and a move assignment. If the function takes a forwarding reference, it's a direct assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect forwarding function. It accepts an argument of any value category and any type which can be assigned to a `bar`.

This means that if you pass an lvalue `bar`, you'll get copy assignment. If you pass an rvalue `bar` you'll get move assignment (assuming it has the operator defined):

```
Bar b{};
my_foo.SetBar(b);           //copy
my_foo.SetBar(std::move(b)) //move
my_foo.SetBar(Bar{});       //move
```

Additionally, any arguments you pass which are convertible to `bar` (via a user-defined conversion operator or an implicit constructor in `bar`) will not require conversion to get to the parameter type, they will be converted at the assignment operator call (unless there's a direct assignment operator for that type anyway).